# Do the 'aura' abilities in the Vendettas campaign affect the player character too?

Tags: the-darkness-2

I am playing the [Vendettas campaign](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Vendettas) offline (singleplayer) as [Inugami](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Inugami), and noticed that he has 'aura' abilities, like '[Dark Melee Aura](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEFen.jpg)'. It is described as "*Players standing close to Inugami receive a damage bonus to their melee strikes.*"

[image: Dark Melee Aura]

Does this only affect allied players, or does this affect the player character too? Also, what about the other 'aura' abilities of Inugami and the other [Vendettas characters](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Vendettas)?

Answer (score 1):

It only applies to allies and minion.

Comment: Inugami has a minion? Or do you mean "other players" by "minion"? Or did you mean this to be about [Jimmy Wilson](http://thedarkness.wikia.com/wiki/Jimmy_Wilson) (who can summon darklings)?

Comment: Second and third one.